# mysql convert decimal time to xx:xx format

Tags: php, mysql, time, decimal

I am trying to convert a decimal time into an actual time format with hours and minutes, ie: in xx:xx hours.

My query is:

```
select SUM(vt.vluchtdec) AS vluchttijddecimal

from tbl_vluchtgegevens vg

left join tbl_vluchttijd vt
on vg.vluchttijddec = vt.vluchttijdID

WHERE vg.vertrekdatum <=NOW();
```

And I am echoing

```
. $row['vluchttijddecimal'] .
```

I have also tried this, but this also still gives me my response in a decimal format:

```
$result = mysql_query("select SUM(vt.vluchtdec) AS vluchttijddecimal

from tbl_vluchtgegevens vg

left join tbl_vluchttijd vt
on vg.vluchttijddec = vt.vluchttijdID

WHERE vg.vertrekdatum <=NOW();");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$dec = $row['vluchttijddecimal'];
function 
convertTime($dec)
{
// start by converting to seconds
$seconds = $dec * 3600;
// we're given hours, so let's get those the easy way
$hours = floor($dec);
// since we've "calculated" hours, let's remove them from the seconds variable
$seconds -= $hours * 3600;
// calculate minutes left
$minutes = floor($seconds / 60);
// remove those from seconds as well
$seconds -= $minutes * 60;
// return the time formatted HH:MM:SS
return lz($hours).":".lz($minutes).":".lz($seconds);
}

// lz = leading zero
function lz($num)
{
return (strlen($num) < 2) ? "0{$num}" : $num;
}

echo "" .$dec."";
```

In MS Access I would do something like this:

```
CInt([vluchttijddecimal]) & ":" & Format([vluchttijddecimal]*60 Mod 60;"00")
```

But this does not work or I don't know how to do so in MySQL / php.

Comment: What format is the decimal time in?? Number of minutes? Timestamp? Datetime??

Comment: it is hours.minutes so for example, 9:30 would be 9.5 .. I wanted to just sum the time, but everyone told me that was not the best idea so I moved to decimal.

Comment: Summing time can be done, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i am trying to find the total hours of something, which is going to be greater than 24 hours. currently it is at 512.1 which should mean 512 hours 10 minutes

Comment: "everyone" was wrong. it is the best idea to keep time in database as either simple integer specifying number of minutes, or use databases time column format, and convert to hours/minutes just at the output time. Didn't my answer work for you?

Answer (score 8):

For anyone that is interested... This is how you would convert decimal time (Where 0.1 == 6 minutes) to hours and minutes (0.2333 == 14 minutes) in MYSQL alone. no PHP is needed. This also accounts for the need to round seconds to minutes.

```
SELECT CONCAT(FLOOR(timeInDec),':', LPAD(ROUND((timeInDec - FLOOR(timeInDec)) * 60) % 60,2,0)) AS TimeInHoursMinutes
FROM YourTable;
```

Replace timeInDec with the column name that contains the decimal time you would like to convert.

This will return 0:06 for 0.1000 decimal value so leading zeros are accounted for in single digit minutes.

Comment: This is the correct answer for any application using purely mySQL. Just replace the "timeInDec" variable with an actual variable or statement where the output is an amount of hours in decimal format and it will work. I've proven it three different ways and it is great. Thanks ozfive.

Answer (score 6):

You can do this in you SQL statement something like this:

```
SELECT CONCAT(CEIL(mydecimal),':', LPAD(Floor(mydecimal*60 % 60),2,'0')) as formated text
```

Where mydecimal is your unformatted field name

Answer (score 0):

I think I have calculated your time values... although it was kinda pain.

It appears your "decimal time" is "hours.minutes"? Rather horrible and definitely not a good format: for dealing with time its best to stick to integers that specify either a total of minutes/seconds/hours or whatever granularity you need.

But assuming it is hours.minutes, you should be able to do it like this in PHP:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$dec = $row['vluchttijddecimal'];
return sprintf("%2d:%2d", floor($dec), floor(($dec - floor($dec))*100));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully I am correct in assuming that you mean, for example that 2.5 hours = 2H 30mins. If so, then your 'time' is a time interval and is best represented by the [DateInterval](http://php.net/dateinterval) class.

This function will do what you want:-

```
/**
 * Converts a 'decimal time' in the format 1.5hours to DateInterval object
 * 
 * @param Int $decimalTime
 * @return DateInterval
 */
function decTimeToInterval($decimalTime)
{
    $hours = floor($decimalTime);
    $decimalTime -= $hours;
    $minutes = floor($decimalTime * 60);
    $decimalTime -= ($minutes/60);
    $seconds = floor($decimalTime * 3600);

    $interval = new \DateInterval("PT{$hours}H{$minutes}M{$seconds}S");
    return $interval;
}

echo decTimeToInterval(512.168)->format("%H:%I:%S");
```

[See it working](http://3v4l.org/88cqu)

If you want to add times in the format 'H:i' without converting them to and from decimals, you can do it like this:-

```
function sumTimes($time1, $time2)
{
    list($hours1, $minutes1) = explode(':', $time1);
    list($hours2, $minutes2) = explode(':', $time2);
    $totalHours = $hours1 + $hours2;
    $totalMinutes = $minutes1 + $minutes2;
    if($totalMinutes >= 60){
        $hoursInMins = floor($totalMinutes/60);
        $totalHours += $hoursInMins;
        $totalMinutes -= ($hoursInMins * 60);
    }
    return "$totalHours:$totalMinutes";
}

echo sumTimes('12:54', '100:06') . PHP_EOL;
echo sumTimes('12:54', '100:20') . PHP_EOL;
```

[See it working](http://3v4l.org/cqKsr)

Comment: so this seems like it has great potential, when I put in $row['vluchttijddec'] at 
echo decTimeToInterval($row['vluchttijddec'])->format("%H:%I:%S"); 
I get something completely different from what I was expecting. I get 4:54 and it should be more like 512:10

Comment: What is the value of $row['vluchttijddec']?

Comment: What would you expect to see if your number of hours is greater than 24?

Comment: vascowhite - the current expected value is 512:10 meaning that the total time is 512 hours and 10 minutes...

Comment: @DaniëlCronk Sorry, I misunderstood your requirement, please see my edit. This revised code should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I used for my Payroll System:

```
SELECT If(total_late>0, LPAD(CONCAT(REPLACE(FLOOR(total_late/60) + FORMAT(total_late%60*0.01,2), '.', ':'), ':00'), 8, 0), '00:00:00') FROM MyTable
```

I multiplied it by 0.01 because my variables are in Seconds. Eg. 60.00 = 1min

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest this to include seconds. It is based on @Richard's solutions. Just notice I've changed CEIL by FLOOR in @Richard's solution.

```
SET @timeInDec=1.505;
SELECT CONCAT(FLOOR(@timeInDec),':', LPAD(FLOOR(@timeInDec*60 % 60),2,'0'),':', LPAD(FLOOR(MOD(@timeInDec*60 % 60,1)*100),2,0)) as timeInDec;
```